# Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?

Tags: command-line, server, keyboard-layout

I use 12.04 Server in command line mode (no X installed), and I would like to change the keyboard layout. How can I do this?

Comment: Mike, would you consider changing the accepted answer? It looks like there is a much better answer now than the originally accepted answer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Please try the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

If it says you don't have the package, then install console-data with:

```
sudo apt-get install console-data
```

More about Locale Configuration: [LocaleConf - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf)

Comment: Like that other answer mentions: This does not carry over a reboot. (tested in 12.04.1 LTS)

Comment: A hint for people who want to change their keyboard layout during console install: Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add 'universe' to the listed URL. Otherwise it can't find consol-data

Answer (score 269):

After trying `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`, I found out that it doesn't work after a reboot.

However,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

does work after reboot and also has more options.

[More info here.](http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions)

Comment: How do I find out what kind of keyboard I have? It's the Windows 8 Surface pro one. What's the US standard one?

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the other one.

Comment: Older Ubuntu releases, such as Lucid Lynx (10.04), don't have the keyboard-configuration package. Göran's link has the correct answer for these: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` If your cursor keys don't work as expected in the ncurses UI, try those on the numeric keypad.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu Server 20.04 with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ For some reason I had to be **connected to the internet** if I wanted the command to work properly and for the changes to stay active even after rebooting.

Answer (score 47):

Try:

`loadkeys es` *(Spanish)*
`loadkeys pt` *(Portuguese)*
`loadkeys br` *(Brazilian Portuguese)*
`loadkeys ch` *(Swiss German)*

Comment: doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04, keyboard layout in the console remains the same

Comment: `loadkeys de` for german keyboard layout worked for me, thx!

Comment: `loadkeys ru` worked for russian, ctrl + shift to toggle between english and russian

Answer (score 17):

For Ubuntu Desktop, you can use:

- Set US layout: `setxkbmap us`
- Set GB layout: `setxkbmap gb`

Comment: This commands only works for Ubuntu Desktop, not on Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 6):

For me this did it

`localectl set-keymap de-latin1`

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue on a console mode only VM.

The solution in my case was editing `/etc/default/keyboard` and changing the

```
XKBLAYOUT="de"
```

line (a german VM) to

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
```

to work with my US keyboard and then rebooting.

Comment: I believe this only works with a GUI. Also - the reboot is not really required, you can also set the variable in the current terminal by simply overwriting it. `XKBLAYOUT="us"`

Comment: It also works on Ubuntu 20 (focal)

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu 13.10 Server as a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox, this worked for me:

(no GUI, only command-line mode)

Default keyboard layout was French, 'AZERTY'

`loadkeys us` (English, was not *'en'* for me, as some docs state)

Note that you will likely have to run the command as `sudo loadkeys us`.

Comment: You might want to edit your last line and use `sudo` instead of `root`, since root is not the recommended method for commands needing administrator priviledges.

Comment: I could not get `loadkeys us` to work, even with `sudo`. It was saying that the file "us" couldn't be found. This on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded today configuring this on my Raspberry Pi 3 via:

- generating the required locale `locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8`
- calling `loadkeys de`

Answer (score 0):

so many potential solutions, but here is what helped me in the end:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

if it failes with something like `locales not found`, install the package `locales` and rerun the above command.