# Slash ("/") in Thinkpad T420 ABNT keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T420 with a Brazilian ABNT keyboard layout. This is a rather unique layout where the slash is between the context menu key and the arrow keys.

[image]

However, the slash key does not work! How could I make it work?

Comment: You sir get the weirdest thinkpad keyboard layout award.  I'm really not sure what advantage this keyboard layout has really.  I would prefer to give up my Context key over my control but I guess the thinkpad creators thought otherwise.  Shrug oh well.  It is shame ABNT is interpreted this way on Thinkpad computers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the system-wide keyboard configuration (including TTY), by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

as described [in this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/158895/430591).

To choose the `thinkpadz60` layout shown in [@brandizzi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184466/430591), select the "IBM ThinkPad Z60m/Z60t/Z61m/Z61t" layout in the list. It should be above the "Generic PC" layout:

[image]

EDIT: Also works on Debian

Answer (score 4):

I solved it (in part) by adding the following line in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="thinkpadz60"
```

Actually, I replaced the line `XKBMODEL=""`  with `XKBMODEL="thinkpadz60"`. Then, I restarted the notebook. (Actually, I believe one would have just to restart X by running `restart lightd` or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>. I suspect that it is even possible to reload this X configuration without restarting it but I have not found how to do it yet.)

Unfortunately, the key still does not work at the text terminals. However, since I use (most of the time) the GNOME Terminal instead of the pure text ones, it is a minor nuisance because it works in the terminal emulator.

(If you do not get it working yet, you can also type slash by pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and question mark by typing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Lenovo notebook with the BR ABNT keyboard. I was able to fix the slash key for text terminals.

1. Go to `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty`.
2. Copy the original map `br-abnt2.map.gz` to a temp directory.
3. Decompress the file and rename it to `br-thinkpad.map` (example, you can use any name you like).
4. Edit the file `br-thinkpad.map` with a text editor.
5. Insert the following line:

   ```
   keycode  97 = slash question degree
   ```

   I inserted the line respecting the order of the other keycodes in the file.
6. Save the file.
7. Compress the file with `gzip br-thinkpad.map`.
8. Copy the compressed file to `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty`.
9. Test the file with the command `loadkeys br-thinkpad`.
10. To make the change permanent edit `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`, changing the value of `KEYTABLE` to `br-thinkpad.map.gz`.

Comment: Works well for me. tks

Answer (score 1):

I recently update to Ubuntu 22.04 and the keyboard stop working... The problem was that Gnome back to work on Wayland.
I restart the screen session with Gnome on XOrg and the slash "/" key back to work.

Just for improve the information above ;)