# Slash ("/") key not working in login screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, login-screen, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my ThinkPad E480 and noticed the slash key "/" was not working. Digging a bit, I found this article where the OP has a keyboard layout really close to mine (abnt with slash key close to the arrows keys) [Slash ("/") in Thinkpad T420 ABNT keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184465/slash-in-thinkpad-t420-abnt-keyboard/184466#184466)

I followed the proposed solution https://askubuntu.com/a/769358/1193030 and it worked for all the system, but not for the login screen, where the key "/" keep not being recognized.

This is what I have in the `/etc/default/keyboard` file:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="thinkpad60"
XKBLAYOUT="br"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Edit: For XKBMODEL, i tried `thinkpad60` and `thinkpadz60`. Both work fine when I'm already logged in, but not in the login screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `XKBMODEL` set in the other question was `thinkpadz60`, not `thinkpad60`. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, but I tried it before. I'll put it into the question

Comment: Maybe GDM isn't able to make use of the `XKBMODEL` value. You may want to file a [GDM issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. When you can (in a day or two), accept your answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to solve the problem.

I had launched `gnome-control-center` with sudo from a terminal and under `Region & Language` added in `Input Sources` the layout **Portuguese(Brazil, IBM/Lenovo ThinkPad)** and then restarted the computer.

In the login screen, the key `/` began to work, but after the login, the key didn't work anymore. Then, I repeated the process but without `sudo`.

The screenshots for the process are given below.

- Execute gnome-control-center with sudo
  [image]
- Added Portuguese(Brazil, IBM/Lenovo ThinkPad) layout
  [image]
- Added Portuguese(Brazil, IBM/Lenovo ThinkPad) layout without sudo
  [image]