# Backslash not working

Tags: bash

I am facing a problem with my backslash. whenever i press control backslash this (#) comes out. I tried to press alt right that doesn't work as well. Initially everything was working perfect this happened after removing the debug port. If anyone knows the solution please try to help me as i am writing my dissertation  on latex and this key is really crucial.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your keyboard layout? 
Open `System Settings > Keyboard Layout`

Answer (score 3):

It's just a keyboard configuration issue. Your computer assumes your keyboard is American but it's actually British (or something else with *that* crossover). It's fairly simlpe to fix from a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

[As stolen from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server).