# VirtualBox causes OS start failure

Tags: virtualbox

On Kubuntu 14.04, rebooting after installing virtualbox-5.0_5.0.14-105127-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64 results in a text (terminal like) user login name and password  prompt. Entry results in "incorrect password" message and repeat login prompt. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the terminal keyboard is set to default settings, meaning the US keyboard, and you use some special keys in your password. Use a picture of the US keyboard end enter your password.

[Link to Pics of US Keyboard](https://www.google.ch/search?q=us%20keyboard&client=browser-ubuntu&hs=mGc&channel=fe&hl=en&biw=1421&bih=815&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1kMHx-ebKAhVIHxoKHZzaBlcQ_AUIBygB)

**Update:** Just comes to my mind....

Try to boot an older kernel in 'Advanced options for Ubuntu', if there is one available (press left < shift > key right after your computers BIOS/UEFI screen, if you don't see the GRUB boot menu). Your system may boot normally then.

To configure your console keyboard, once logged in...

[Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server)