# How to change keyboard layout in tty?

Tags: keyboard-layout, tty

I have changed the keyboard layout from English (UK) to English (US) via System Settings. But it just works for GUI, the keyboard layout on tty remained unchanged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server)

Comment: What is in "/etc/default/locale" file?