# How to set the correct keyboard on Ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via Hyper-V.
During the setup it asked me some questions regarding my Keyboard layout, however, after the install; my keyboard isn't set right. the | key gives out a weird A with a dot on top and quotes "" give unknown symbols.

How can I fix my keyboard without reinstalling the OS (hopefully?) 
Please keep in mind I am a newbie so need detailed instructions?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently you selected the wrong layout. Why Ubuntu server? You need to familiarize yourself with the plain desktop before anything else.

Comment: i just have a command-line to work with? How can I make that possible thru command-line? keep in mind im a newbie? thnx

Comment: Please read again. I haven't noticed you installed server.

Comment: Server gives me more options later down the line, that with desktop I might not have, that's why? Is there a way to fix it in the server-os?

Comment: No, completely wrong. There's no significant difference apart from the server not having a desktop (which can be installed as well) and the desktop not having some tools preinstalled (but they can be installed later if needed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server)

Comment: Please edit your question and 1. tell us which keyboard you use and 2. show us the output of the command `setxkbmap -query`

Comment: Gunnar- I am using my HP - laptop and to answer the setxkbmap -query, it says:
cannot open display "default display"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

It should give you all the options, and the configuration persist on reboot

Comment: Excellent this fixed my problem. thanks arturodr.

@CelticWarrior, how <bold>hard</bold> was this to answer, rather than going into a debate into why I installed server vs desktop? How hard?

Comment: @gsb005 Apparently you didn't read the duplicate which mentions this and a lot more. BTW, the newbie - arturodr - who answered should instead flag the duplicate. It's not about being easy or hard, it's about the site's policy and (bad) attitude from a Windows "power user" with the usual sense of entitlement and knowledge that doesn't match reality.